# ARM Assembly Bitwise Operator and Number Systems

Tags: assembly, arm

For bitwise AND, if I do AND X5,X4,#3, does that automatically perform AND on the binary value stored in X4 and 00000011 then store the resultant binary value in X5? Since 00000011 = 2^0 + 2^1 = 3 in decimal. Am I correct to assume that in Assembly, you write the value in base 10(like #3), but when performing bitwise operation, compiler automatically converts the decimal value to binary? Similarly, if a register is initialized in hexadecimal like MOV X20, #0xABFD, then if we do a bitwise operation on X20, compiler first automatically converts #0xABFD to binary?

Comment: It is an assembler not a compiler, and the syntax is specific to the assembler not the target (arm).  But yes a #12 if that is supported by the assembler and we assume that is a decimal 12 then no matter what programming language the tools are going to make that a 1100 binary (assuming it represents some value)(bcd is an exception, but the 1970s ended a long time ago).  Likewise 0xABCD will be converted from base 16 to base 1.   These numbers in the ascii file are ascii and the assembler or compiler has to deal with them and computers are binary....

Comment: Yup, converting human-readable numbers in source code to binary machine code (along with mnemonics and register name) is the entire point of an assembler.  Always, not just for bitwise instructions.